# org-dartlang-app:/web_entrypoint.dart:16:22: Error: Undefined name 'main'. return (entrypoint.main as _NullaryFunction)();

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

hi i try to open flutter app on chrome and that what happen.org-dartlang-app:/web_entrypoint.dart:16:22: Error: Undefined name 'main'.
return (entrypoint.main as _NullaryFunction)();
my code:`

```
        import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
  class hellp extends StatefulWidget {
    const hellp({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);
  
    @override
    State<hellp> createState() => _hellpState();
  }
  
  class _hellpState extends State<hellp> {
    @override
    Widget build( BuildContext context) {
      return Container(
        
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please share you code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just faced this error message while attempting to test a code snippet I found online. Mine was with a stateless widget though.

I solved it by adding the following code after the import statements:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() { //add this
    runApp(const MyApp());
}

//using stateless widget here.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
```

Hope this helps :)